# How to parameterize a curve by arc-length, if the curve's position at time t=0 does not coincide with the origin.

Tags: calculus, arc-length

$$ \mathbf x = \begin{bmatrix} x_1 \\ x_2 \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} \sinh t \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}$$
$ \mathrm D $ is the derivative operator. 
$$ \mathrm D \mathbf x (t) = \begin{bmatrix} \cosh t \\ 0 \end{bmatrix} $$
$$ (\mathrm d s)^2 = \mathrm d t \mathrm D^\mathtt T \mathbf x (t) \mathrm D \mathbf x (t) \mathrm d t $$
$$ \int \mathrm d s = \int \cosh t \, \mathrm d t $$
$$ s (t) = \int_{q=0}^{q=t} \cosh q \, \mathrm d q = \sinh t - \sinh 0 = \sinh t $$
Proposition: 
$$ x_1 (t=0) = 0 \land x_2 (t=0) = 0 \implies \int \sqrt {\mathrm D^\mathtt T \mathbf x (0) \mathrm D \mathbf x (0)} \, \mathrm d t =  0 + c  $$ 
Here is the question: Under what conditions is the proposition true?
If the proposition is false, then I think the arc-length, $ \mathit s $, at time $\mathrm d t $ can be some quite large quantity; this situation would be difficult to interpret.

Comment: I am beginning to think the question I posed is a dumb question.